# Custom Ajax Authrorization filter in WebAPI(Not working)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using angularJs with Webapi (which is using form authetication).
When i use authroize attribute in webabpi and send a ajax request from client  i recieve a http 302 response but i want to send http 401 directly from the server  when the request is ajax request and 302 response when the request is complete page referesh request .I have tried making custom action filter but i did not get any sucess still i get http 302

```
 public class AuthorizeFilter : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public AuthorizeFilter()
            : base()
        {

        }
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

            throw new HttpResponseException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) ;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What can happen is that there is a form authentication module running on server, on seeing unauthorized response it can send you transparently to the login page which is done using 302 i believe. Can you directly make a webapi request form browser and see, what status code you get.

Comment: @Chandermani, I agree. If you take a look at wikipedia, 302 is defined as a way of doing redirection - forms based authentication works by checking if the user is authenticated then redirects to the login page. EDIT: Depending on the platform, you may need to disable modules in the WebServer and re-implement the authentication mechanisms or simply change your code accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unauthorised webapi call returning login page rather than 401](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149750/unauthorised-webapi-call-returning-login-page-rather-than-401)