# Unauthorised webapi call returning login page rather than 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

How do I configure my mvc/webapi project so that a webapi method called from a razor view doesn't return the loginpage when its unauthorised?

Its a MVC5 application which also has WebApi controllers for calls via javascript.

The two methods below

```
[Route("api/home/LatestProblems")]      
[HttpGet()]
public List<vmLatestProblems> LatestProblems()
{
    // Something here
}

[Route("api/home/myLatestProblems")]
[HttpGet()]
[Authorize(Roles = "Member")]
public List<vmLatestProblems> mylatestproblems()
{
   // Something there
}
```

are called via the following angular code:

```
angular.module('appWorship').controller('latest', 
    ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope,$http) {         
        var urlBase = baseurl + '/api/home/LatestProblems';
        $http.get(urlBase).success(function (data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        $http.get(baseurl + '/api/home/mylatestproblems')
          .success(function (data) {
            $scope.data2 = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });  
    }]
);
```

So I'm not logged in and the first method successfully returns data. the second method returns (in the success function) data which contains the equivalent of a login page. i.e. what you would get in mvc if you requested a controller action which was stamped with [Authorize] and you weren't logged in.

I want it to return a 401 unauthorized, so that i can display different data for users based on if they are logged in or not.  Ideally if the user is logged in i want to be able to access the Controller's User property so i can return data specific to that Member.

**UPDATE: Since none of the suggestions below seem to work anymore (changes to Identity or WebAPI) ive created a raw example on [github](https://github.com/tbertenshaw/MVCAPI) which should illustrate the problem.**

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There are two AuthorizeAttribute implementations and you need to make sure you are referencing the correct one for Web API's.  There is [*System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which is used for Web API's, and [*System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which is used for controllers with views.  *Http.AuthorizeAttribute* will return a 401 error if authorization fails and *Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute* will redirect to the login page.

**Updated 11/26/2013**

So it appears things have drastically changed with MVC 5 as Brock Allen pointed out [in his article](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/using-cookie-authentication-middleware-with-web-api-and-401-response-codes/).  I guess the OWIN pipeline takes over and introduces some new behavior.   Now when the user is not authorized a status of 200 is returned with the following information in the HTTP header.

```
X-Responded-JSON: {"status":401,"headers":{"location":"http:\/\/localhost:59540\/Account\/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FTestBasic"}}
```

You could change your logic on the client side to check this information in the header to determine how to handle this, instead of looking for a 401 status on the error branch.

I tried to override this behavior in a custom *AuthorizeAttribute* by setting the status in the response in the *OnAuthorization* and *HandleUnauthorizedRequest* methods.

```
actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

But this did not work. The new pipeline must grab this response later and modify it to the same response I was getting before.  Throwing an HttpException did not work either as it is just changed into a 500 error status.

I tested Brock Allen's solution and it did work when I was using a jQuery ajax call. If it is not working for you my guess is that it is because you are using angular.  Run your test with Fiddler and see if the following is in your header.

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

If it is not then that is the problem. I am not familiar with angular but if it lets you insert your own header values then add this to your ajax requests and it will probably start working.

Comment: i think im using System.web.http.authorizeattribute, at least this webapicontroller doesnt have a using for system.web.mvc, and going to definition of the authorize attribute sends me to system.web.http

Comment: Hi @kevin-junghans thoroughly confused here. the example above from shiva uses a mvc authorization attribute which surely i shouldnt be applying to a webapi action, The example from Brock allen doesnt appear to work either it doesnt think its a ajax request when i step through.

Comment: only just spotted this answer (think stackoverflow not sending notifications) I've added a github example to illustrate the problem, and now added your fix to the angular headers. Thanks. It doesn't seem right however that there isn't a property in the authorize attribute that I can check or the original functionality you mentioned doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Using POSTMAN and header param X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest works for me... thanks

Comment: So, what if you have what you intend to be a pure Web API project doing this?  I'm working on a project someone else set up and the Authorize is redirecting as described here, but I have a different API project that works fine.  There must be something making this think it's an MVC app rather than an API app, but I can't find what might be junking it up.

Comment: @DerekGreer - You will need to provide more details and code for your specific issue in order to get any help. Recommend you create another Question with the details as comments is not a good mechanism for this.

Comment: My issue ended up being that the web api project was configured with forms auth in IIS.

Comment: I'm with the same issue of detecting 401 status code. I'm using ajax calls and expecting JSON results. How can I detect 401 situation in jQuery promise?

Answer (score 133):

Brock Allen has a nice blog post on how to return 401 for ajax calls when using Cookie authentication and OWIN.
http://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/using-cookie-authentication-middleware-with-web-api-and-401-response-codes/

Put this in ConfigureAuth method in the Startup.Auth.cs file:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
  AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
  LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
  Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
  {
    OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
    {
      if (!IsAjaxRequest(ctx.Request))
      {
        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
      }
    }
  }
});

private static bool IsAjaxRequest(IOwinRequest request)
{
  IReadableStringCollection query = request.Query;
  if ((query != null) && (query["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"))
  {
     return true;
  }
  IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;
  return ((headers != null) && (headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"));
}
```

Comment: A variation on this: If all your Web API calls go through a certain path, e.g. `/api`, you can use the path to determine whether to redirect. It's especially useful if you have clients that use other formats like JSON. Replace the call to `IsAjaxRequest` with `if (!context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")))`.

Comment: Late to the party, but this method is the only one that worke for me, and seems to be more "accurate."

Comment: Even late(r) to the party, but this has proven very useful... it boggles my mind that the default generated code does this so wrong, in such a frustratingly difficult manner to debug.

Comment: If you're after a WebApi solution, Manik's answer is a good alternative to the highly voted comment here.

Comment: Using C# 6, here is a smaller version of IsAjaxRequest:

`private static bool IsAjaxRequest(IOwinRequest request)
{
    return request.Query?["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest" ||
            request.Headers?["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
}`

Comment: For WebAPI, you can look in the comments for `IsJsonRequest` and integrate that too; you could also use the Accept header

Comment: My application requests from desktop software to the Web Api. Adding the XMLHttpRequest into my headers saved me HOURS of figuring out why I was getting a 404. I added logic to determine if I needed to add the parameter, and then did so (sorry, this app's in VB): 

    If addXMLHttpRequest Then
        request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    End If

Answer (score 94):

If you are adding asp.net WebApi inside asp.net MVC web site you probably want to respond unauthorized to some requests. But then ASP.NET infrastructure come into play and when you try to set response status code to HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized you will get 302 redirect to login page.

If you are using asp.net identity and owin based authentication here a code that can help to solve that issue:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
            {
                if (!IsApiRequest(ctx.Request))
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
}


private static bool IsApiRequest(IOwinRequest request)
{
    string apiPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/api/");
    return request.Uri.LocalPath.StartsWith(apiPath);
}
```

Comment: i changed the discriminant to check if the requests accept text/html or application/xhtml as response, if they don't i assume it's an "automated" client requesting, such an ajax request

Comment: I prefer this approach too.  The only addition I made was to convert LocalPath .ToLower() in case they request "/API" or something.

Comment: Is anybody having luck with this? CookieAuthenticationOptions no longer has a Provider property as of aspnet core 1.1.

Answer (score 29):

I got the same situation when OWIN always redirects 401 response to Login page from WebApi.Our Web API supports not only ajax calls from Angular but also Mobile, Win Form calls. Therefore, the solution to check whether the request is ajax request is not really sorted for our case.

I have opted another approach is to inject new header response: `Suppress-Redirect` if responses come from webApi. The implementation is on handler:

```
public class SuppressRedirectHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            var response = task.Result;
            response.Headers.Add("Suppress-Redirect", "True");
            return response;
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And register this handler in global level of WebApi:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new SuppressRedirectHandler());
```

So, on OWIN startup you are able to check whether response header has `Suppress-Redirect`:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        AuthenticationType = DefaultApplicationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(48),

        LoginPath = new PathString("/NewAccount/LogOn"),

        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
            {
                var response = ctx.Response;
                if (!IsApiResponse(ctx.Response))
                {
                    response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private static bool IsApiResponse(IOwinResponse response)
{
    var responseHeader = response.Headers;

    if (responseHeader == null) 
        return false;

    if (!responseHeader.ContainsKey("Suppress-Redirect"))
        return false;

    if (!bool.TryParse(responseHeader["Suppress-Redirect"], out bool suppressRedirect))
        return false;

    return suppressRedirect;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Our APIs worked on every plateform, except Xamarin/Android. Will use this solution

Answer (score 18):

In previous versions of ASP.NET, you had to [do a whole bunch of stuff](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) to get this working.

The good news is, since you are using ASP.NET 4.5. you can disable forms authentication redirect using the new [HttpResponse.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.suppressformsauthenticationredirect.aspx) property.

In `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        HttpApplication context = (HttpApplication)sender;
        context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
}
```

**EDIT**: You might also want to take a look [at this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/655086/Handling-authentication-specific-issues-for-AJAX-c) by Sergey Zwezdin which has a more refined way of accomplishing what you are trying to do.

Relevant code snippets and author narration pasted below. Original Author of code and narration -- [Sergey Zwezdin](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=3873321).

First – let’s determine whether current HTTP-request is AJAX-request. If yes, we should disable replacing HTTP 401 with HTTP 302:

```
public class ApplicationAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        var response = httpContext.Response;

        if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
            response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Second – let’s add a condition:: if user authenticated, then we will send HTTP 403; and HTTP 401 otherwise.

```
public class ApplicationAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        var response = httpContext.Response;
        var user = httpContext.User;

        if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            else
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;

            response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
            response.End();
        }

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Well done. Now we should replace all usings of standard AuthorizeAttribute with this new filter. It may be not applicable for sime guys, who is aesthete of code. But I don’t know any other way. If you have, let’s go to comments, please.

The last, what we should to do – to add HTTP 401/403 handling on a client-side. We can use ajaxError at jQuery to avoid code duplication:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr) {
    if (xhr.status == 401)
        window.location = "/Account/Login";
    else if (xhr.status == 403)
        alert("You have no enough permissions to request this resource.");
});
```

The result –

- If user is not authenticated, then he will be redirected to a login
  page after any AJAX-call.
- If user is authenticated, but have no enough permissions, then he will see user-friendly erorr message.
- If user is authenticated and have enough permissions, the there is no any errors and HTTP-request will be proceeded as usual.

Comment: Im I'm using the new identity framework for auth via mvc. Would this setting not prevent the mvc login from working as well as the webapi calls?

Comment: when i checked this example it appears the Authorize Attribute being used is the MVC version rather than the WebApi version. however the webapi version doesnt have options for suppressing forms authentiucation.

Comment: my request doesn't have a IsAjaxRequest method.

Comment: Tim look at this for the IsAjaxRequest: http://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/using-cookie-authentication-middleware-with-web-api-and-401-response-codes/   If you are using AngularJs without editing the headers you won't have "XMLHttpRequest" and either add it or check for something else.

Answer (score 11):

If you are running your `Web API` from within your `MVC` project, you'll need to create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` to apply to your `API` methods. Within the `IsAuthorized` `override` you need to grab the current `HttpContext` in order prevent the redirection, like this:

```
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name))
        {
            var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
            response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            response.End();
        }

        return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Using Azure Active Directory integration myself, the approach using the `CookieAuthentication` middleware didn't work for me. I had to do the following:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ...
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {   
            ...         
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
            {
                if (!context.Request.Accept.Contains("html"))
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                }
            },
            ...
        }
    });
```

If the request comes from the browser itself (and not an AJAX call, for instance) then the Accept header will contain the string `html` in it somewhere. Only when the client accepts HTML I will consider a redirect something useful.

My client application can handle the 401 informing the user that the app has no more access and needs to reload to login again.

Comment: This is very similar to the solution proposed for a related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997674/identity-server-3-401-on-ajax-calls-instead-of-302

Answer (score 7):

I also had an MVC5 application (System.Web) with WebApi (using OWIN) and just wanted to prevent 401 responses from WebApi being changed to 302 responses.

What worked for me was to create a customised version of the WebApi AuthorizeAttribute like this:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
    }
}
```

And to use it in place of the standard WebApi AuthorizeAttribute.  I used the standard MVC AuthorizeAttribute to keep the MVC behaviour unchanged.

Comment: Works, but now I have the problem that client receives status -1 instead of 401

Comment: @SebastiánRojas I'm not sure what would be causing that - setting the `SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect`  flag caused it to just return the existing 401 for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just install following NeGet Package

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin

Write following code in WebApiConfig file.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //Web API configuration and services
        //Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
    }
}
```

Comment: All I needed to do was add this filter and its working `config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));` otherwise `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always `false`

Answer (score 2):

Mixing MVC and WebAPI, if the request is unauthorized then it will redirect to login page even in WebAPI request also. For that, we can add below code to send a response to mobile application

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    if (httpContext == null)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        return;
    }

    actionContext.Response = httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false ?
        actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
      System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized") :
       actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
      System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden");

    httpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
    httpContext.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to catch Content-Type == application/json you can use that code:

```
private static bool IsAjaxRequest(IOwinRequest request)
    {
        IReadableStringCollection queryXML = request.Query;
        if ((queryXML != null) && (queryXML["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        IReadableStringCollection queryJSON = request.Query;
        if ((queryJSON != null) && (queryJSON["Content-Type"] == "application/json"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        IHeaderDictionary headersXML = request.Headers;
        var isAjax = ((headersXML != null) && (headersXML["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"));

        IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;
        var isJson = ((headers != null) && (headers["Content-Type"] == "application/json"));

        return isAjax || isJson;

    }
```

regards!!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a hard time getting both the status code and a text response working in the OnAuthorization/HandleUnauthorizedRequest methods.  This turned out to be the best solution for me:

```
    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
        Content = new StringContent(unauthorizedMessage)
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys!

In my case, I combined [cuongle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783681/cuongle) & [Shiva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325521/shiva) 's answers, and got something like this:

In Controller's OnException() handler for API Exceptions:

```
filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
//...
var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
response.Headers.Add("Suppress-Redirect", "true");
response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
```

In App startup config code:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider {
            OnValidateIdentity = ctx => {
                return validateFn.Invoke(ctx);
            },
            OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
            {
                bool enableRedir = true;
                if (ctx.Response != null)
                {
                    string respType = ctx.Response.ContentType;
                    string suppress = ctx.Response.Headers["Suppress-Redirect"];
                    if (respType != null)
                    {
                        Regex rx = new Regex("^application\\/json(;(.*))?$",
                            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                        if (rx.IsMatch(respType))
                        {
                            enableRedir = false;
                        }  
                    }
                    if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(suppress)) && (Boolean.Parse(suppress)))
                    {
                        enableRedir = false;
                    }
                }
                if (enableRedir)
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i thought  "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" is introduced for this specific sccenario. When making ajx calls just add this to your header and server should return proper response.  Atleast this is handled in https://abp.io/

Answer (score 0):

After much fuss trying to avoid the redirections to the login page, I realised that this is actually quite appropriate for the Authorise attribute. It is saying go and get Authorisation. Instead for Api calls which are not authorised, I just wanted not to reveal any information to would be hackers.
This objective was easier to achieve directly by adding a new attribute derived off Authorize which instead hides the content as a 404 error:

```
public class HideFromAnonymousUsersAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
         actionContext.Response = ActionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Access Restricted");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In MVC 5 with Dot Net Framework 4.5.2 we are getting 
"application/json, plaint text.."  under "Accept" header 
It will be nice to use like following:

```
isJson = headers["Content-Type"] == "application/json" || headers["Accept"].IndexOf("application/json", System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```