# Asp.Net Identity: Web Api request fails authorization, returns 200 OK

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am getting up to speed on Asp.Net Identity in .NET 4.5.  I setup a [test app](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project) that registers, logs in, and attempts to make a call to an Api Controller that requires a Claim of "Admin":

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public class WorkController : ApiController
```

When a request is made that does not have the Claim of "Admin", the Web Api still returns 200-OK, but with the JSON of: `{Message:"Authorization has been denied for this request."}`

This seems a little odd to me, since this does not represent successful request.  I was expecting a 401 error.  I am having trouble finding information on how to customize the response, or return a proper status code....I guess I should ask if 401 is even proper for this, or is the 200 the correct status code to use, and I should just handle it?

edit:  For some reason it is now returning 401.  Now I don't understand why I was getting the JSON message earlier if it was denied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was getting the JSON message when the LoginPath for the OwinStartup class was specified.

Comment: I am curious why the LoginPath affects the status code. It makes no sense to me. I want 401 but why can't I specify LoginPath then?

Comment: @Stilgar I wonder too.  My guess is the nature of WebApi vs MVC.  Maybe when the LoginPath is specified WebApi is guessing you want to know that stuff and returns a message instead of an error.

Comment: I've just been scratching my head on this one, and came across this StackOverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149750/unauthorised-webapi-call-returning-login-page-rather-than-401, and this Brock Allen article: http://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/using-cookie-authentication-middleware-with-web-api-and-401-response-codes/ - it seems that it's an unusual behaviour, but there's a workaround for it in the article.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how you fixed the problem and why the LoginPath causes the problem? I can't figure it out from your response. Thanks.

Comment: This link explains it quite well and also provides a solution https://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/using-cookie-authentication-middleware-with-web-api-and-401-response-codes/

Answer (score 1):

The [article](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/using-cookie-authentication-middleware-with-web-api-and-401-response-codes/) referred to above is correct, however I think it doesn't cover the case where the API is being called by a 3rd party application rather than as an ajax request (Testing query["X-Requested-With"] etc).

This is my preference:

in Startup.Configuration() or Startup.ConfigureAuth():

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/LogOn"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
        {
            if (!IsApiRequest(ctx.Request))
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            }
        }
    }
});

private bool IsApiRequest(IOwinRequest request)
{
    return request.Uri.AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/api");
}
```