# ASP.NET WebAPI2 BearerToken redirects to Login page instead of returning 401

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a new web application containing MVC5 and WebAPI. Now I added a new API-Controller and added an Authorize-Atribute (System.Web.Http). Authorizatin works fine, and values are returned. But when the authorization fails, the login-page and status 200 are returned. But i need the error and status 401 to be returned in that case.

I tried and when I remove app.UseCookieAuthentication, the correct status is returned - but I need cookie auth to enable authentication in the normal MVC part.

Of course, I could override Authorization attribute to suppress forms redirect as advised in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149750/unauthorised-webapi-call-returning-login-page-rather-than-401) but I guess this is not the correct way as there exist 2 authorizeattributes and a lot of configuration stuff.

my startup auth:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, 
        ApplicationUser>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});


app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

app.UseOAuthBearerTokens( new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/Token"),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
});
}
```

my oauth provider:

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
{
    // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
    if (context.ClientId == null)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}

public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
{
    if (context.ClientId == "self")
    {
        Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

        if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}

public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}

public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var info = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
    if (info == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        return;
    }

    var oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(info, context.Options.AuthenticationType);
    var cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(info, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string> {
                                                                                        { "userName", info.UserName }
                                                                                    });
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
    context.Validated(ticket);
    context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
}
}
```

Comment: We couldn't get the authorize attribute to return 401 if there is a LoginPath set. Try removing the login path and see the response.

Comment: it worked, but its really strange
what if I need a redirect in forms and a 401 in webapi?

Comment: I believe this is a known issue...https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/634

Comment: @KiranChalla this one is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the 302 `Response`:

```
var c = new CookieAuthenticationOptions;

// Make ASP.NET give us the 302 redirect when cookie is missing/broke
c.AutomaticChallenge = true;

c.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    // Override the 302 redirection with the 401 we actually want 
    OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.FromResult(0); ;
    }
};
```

This is an unpleasant hack, it works, but [I'd love to know a better way of making the built in authentication middleware work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662305/net-core-returning-500-instead-of-401-when-missing-cookie).

Comment: @DevEng From the question: _"I need cookie auth to enable authentication in the normal MVC part"_ - a new visitor should bring a bearer token, but then they want to use a cookie. So check becomes first for cookie, then for bearer, then redirect to the authentication service to get one, but .NET's cookie check always redirects to a login form.