# .NET core returning 500 instead of 401 when missing cookie

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, http-status-code-401

I have a .NET core API that uses cookie authentication. It is accessed by a PWA/SPA that has its own login route.

In `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
    services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>(options =>
    {
        ...

        // Use cookie authentication
        var expiresIn = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0); // 1 hour timeout
        var c = options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie;
        c.AuthenticationScheme = "appSchemeName";
        c.CookieName = "appCookieName";
        c.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;

        // If this is true auth failures become redirects
        c.AutomaticChallenge = false;
        c.SlidingExpiration = true;
        c.ExpireTimeSpan = expiresIn;

        // Store sessions in the cache with the same TTL as the cookie
        c.SessionStore = new MyRedisSessionStore(expiresIn);
    });
    ...
}

public void Configure(...) 
{
    ...
    app.UseIdentity();
    ...
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

In my client side JS I expect a 401 when the authentication cookie is invalid or missing, and display a login form when this is the case.

However, when a user without a valid cookie visits a controller flagged with `[Authorize]` they get a 500 status error:

> InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic

If I change `c.AutomaticChallenge = true;` then I get a 302 redirecting to `{site}/Account/Login?ReturnUrl={api resource it was trying to load}`. That's weird because that's not a valid route and I didn't set it.

How do I fix this so that unauthenticated users get a 401 instead of a 500 exception on the server.

I realise that I can override this and write my own authentication with custom responses, but there must be a way to make the built-in `[Authorize]` return the correct HTTP status code.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code a line at a time during runtime to see which line it breaks on?

Comment: @sam the error is thrown by Microsoft's middleware before it even gets to my code.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this exact issue when I was using Postman to test my endpoints.

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/99aa3bd35dd5fbe46a93eef8a2c8ab1f9fe8d05b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/Events/CookieAuthenticationEvents.cs#L41) for the `OnRedirectToLogin` event, you can see that it is checking if the request is an AJAX request. For `IsAjaxRequest` to return `true`, the `X-Requested-With` header needs to have `XMLHttpRequest` as it's value.

If you happen to be testing this out with Postman, you'll have to manually apply the X-Requested-With along with the correct value:

[image: Image for Postman Settings (can't embed images, yet)]

Finally, this is what your `CookieAuthenticationOptions` should look like if you have no other special configurations that need to be set:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

Comment: Interesting! I'm using `fetch`, which the replacement for `XMLHttpRequest`. The older tech only gets used as a shim. I could add the custom header, but if that's the case it's a pretty severe issue with .NET's handling.

Comment: @Keith Hmmm, I wouldn't say it's a severe issue. When you make an ajax request to an endpoint, you wouldn't want to get the markup for your login page or a 404 in the response would you?

It could definitely be documented better.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the job of the REST API. It's strictly an API that only returns JSON, it should never return a 302 (regardless of what's making the request) because there's no login HTML page to serve up. The server should not be guessing at who's making the request and deciding to redirect them because it thinks the request is from a user (rather than an AJAX request).

Answer (score 2):

I have a *fix* for this, as in I have code that works, but it's horrible and cannot possibly be the best way to handle this.

My current code give me either a 500 server error (when `AutomaticChallenge = false`), or a 302 redirect (when `AutomaticChallenge = true`). Both are useless in my SPA because 500 is too generic and the 302 redirects transparently to a non-existent page and I get a 404 in the client side JS.

My fix is to go with the 302 and then override the `Response`:

```
// Make ASP.NET give us the 302 redirect when cookie is missing/broke
c.AutomaticChallenge = true;

c.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    // Override the 302 redirection with the 401 we actually want 
    OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.FromResult(0); ;
    }
};
```

This works and so it it an answer to this question, but it's a horrible hack around middleware that isn't behaving how I want it to.

Comment: I only wanted a simple one, 401 on unauthenticated, and 403 on unauthorized, so my spa can show the correct info. I'll use this for the time being, until I find a better solution. Thanks!