# Getting ASP.NET Identity to Angular.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-identity-2

I've set up ASP.NET Identity 2 in my MVC app to authorize users for both standard pages and Web API calls.  Simply adding the `[Authorize]` attribute ([with a few fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149750/unauthorised-webapi-call-returning-login-page-rather-than-401#20151056)) works just fine for preventing unauthorized access, but I also need the ability to get the current `IPrinicple` in the same way that I would use `User.Identity` in my MVC views and controllers.  There are some things I can accomplish by using it in my views and controllers before they are handed off to Angular, but I also need to be able to read this value for things like creating menus based on the current user's role.

I've considered reading the ASP.NET Idenity cookies, but this requires decryption of the cookie, which I obviously won't be able to accomplish on the client side without revealing the decryption key.

Is there a way to pass off the `User.Identity` to Angular.js in a way that's consumable by the client side code?

Comment: Why don't you let the server vià web api (or similar) let angularJS know what menus should be rendered? I don't think it is a good design if the GUI layer needs to decide things accoring to user roles. This should be decided on a lower level, IMO.

Comment: Well I'm not exactly letting the GUI itself determine what items to show; It's in a configuration service.  But that does give me an idea:  Maybe creating an `[Authorize]`d Web API call to return the current user...

Comment: @StephenCollins I think that you asked yourself. Add a controller action that returns a UserModel with the properties that you wish, to the client. Obviously with the [Authorize] attribute.