# Why are my AJAX requests not extending an OWIN MVC session?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, owin, session-timeout

We have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that has been using Forms Authentication with sliding expiration.  We recently switched to OWIN Cookie Authentication and are experiencing issues with our sessions not extending properly.

Previously, a session could be extended from an AJAX xhr request.  With this configuration, however, they are not extending.  I'm receiving a 200 for every request (both GET and POST) that should be extending, even after the server has killed the session.

The current setup is:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
   AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
   CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
   CookieName = Constants.CatalystPortalCookieName,
   LoginPath = new PathString(url.Action(nameof(LoginController.Index), "Login")),
   SlidingExpiration = true,
   ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
   CookiePath = "/",
});
```

If I click a link that causes the entire page to be loaded as a document response, however, the server properly extends the session.

Comment: are you using *session.abandon* to kill session/logout? if so that is not correct way with OWIN. With OWIN you should use AuthenticationManager.SignOut method

Comment: If you look at the response headers do you see things like no-cache set? If so you may be hitting a cookie conflict issue: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=System.Web%20response%20cookie%20integration%20issues

Comment: It might be worth cracking open [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and inspecting the requests/responses.

Comment: How are you calling the ajax request? Be sure when you use jQuery to specify `cache:false;`

Comment: did you ever find answer to this?

Comment: @Kyle Check the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having some faulty assumptions.  The AJAX requests **were extending.** The return of the 200 was throwing me off.  After looking with fiddler at the actual response, I saw that with the change to OWIN, the 401 is actually moved in the response:

```
X-Responded-JSON: {"status":401,"headers":{...foo...}}
```

So, we ended up just setting the status of the response back to 401.  That's probably horrible, but it fit our needs.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest() {
    var context = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
    var header = context.Response.Headers["X-Responded-JSON"];
    if (header != null && header.Contains("\"status\":401")) {
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    }
```

Here's probably a more robust solution:  [OWIN: unauthorised webapi call returning login page rather than 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149750/owin-unauthorised-webapi-call-returning-login-page-rather-than-401)