# Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation Custom Authorize Attribute API Redirect

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, owin, ws-federation, okta

So we have integrated `Okta` in our application for an `SSO` solution utilizing the `OWIN` stack and `Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation` nuget package.  It seems to work well overall, however we have a problem when the authorize attribute for `WebApi` is added to the mix.  The custom authorize attribute works as designed for permissions provided via string parameter, however the problem seems to occur with the default behavior of returning a `401 response`.  It seems this 401 is watched for globally as I never hit my custom `OWIN middleware` component to sign in (ie: re-direct to Okta) yet still the API request fails when a `302` is returned which triggers the re-direct to `Okta`.  Every post I have read indicates to follow [this](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/using-cookie-authentication-middleware-with-web-api-and-401-response-codes/) blog post by Brock Allen, however as I mentioned the re-direct never triggers this code.  I thought about building an Angular Interceptor but I don't like that approach at all, so I went with returning a `403 (Forbidden)` for now from the `Authorize` attribute, which isn't ideal but is workable.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149750/owin-unauthorised-webapi-call-returning-login-page-rather-than-401) SO post seems to be the main discussion on this issue but I have had no luck following the advice there.  Here is the middleware code being utilized thus far, does anyone have any thoughts or ideas on how to exclude /api routes from being re-directed to Okta?

```
        var fileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\wwwroot");

        var options = new FileServerOptions()
        {
            FileSystem = fileSystem,
            EnableDefaultFiles = true,
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
        };

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
            new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
                new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MetadataAddress"],
                    Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Wtrealm"],
                    TokenValidationParameters =
                    {
                        ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"]
                    }
                });


        app.Map("/api", x =>
        {
            dependencyResolver = x.UseApi();
        });

        app.UseFileServer(options);
```

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/28/use-owin-azure-ad-to-secure-both-mvc-ux-and-web-api-in-the-same-project/. Although the post uses OIDC, that approach should work with WSFed just as well.

Comment: @vibronet I would love for you to post this as an answer so you get the credit that is due.  That article resolved my problems as I did not know about the HostAuthentication attribute.  I will give you the answer if you post it.  Thanks again that blog never came up in my research!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/28/use-owin-azure-ad-to-secure-both-mvc-ux-and-web-api-in-the-same-project/ - the post is about OIDC but should apply to wsfed just as well.