# Returning 401 Unauthorised from WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my WebAPI, if I detect a Bad Authorisation I use the following;

```
   [HttpPost]
   public HttpResponseMessage CustomerQuotationComplete(Guid apiKey, int EnquiryId, int SiteId, bool accepted)
   {
      if (IsRequestAuthorized())
      {
        ...
      }
      else
      {
          var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { ReasonPhrase = "Bad Authentication" };
          throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
      }
    }
```

However what I am actually receiving a 302 Found response, not a 401 Unauthorized.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can return Unauthorized response

```
[HttpPost]
   public IHttpActionResult CustomerQuotationComplete(Guid apiKey, int EnquiryId, int SiteId, bool accepted)
   {
      if (IsRequestAuthorized())
      {
        ...
      }
      else
      {
          return this.Unauthorized();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't convert this.Unauthorized (Http.Results.UnauthorisedResult)  to type HttpresponseMessage

Comment: See edited example. Changed return type to IHttpActionResult

Comment: This doesnt make any difference either. Its all very strange, must be soemthign else in teh project causing an unexpected result.

Comment: That's why my guess was to create an empty Web API project, to validate your methods works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try to return your message instead of thowing out an exeption:

```
var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { ReasonPhrase = "Bad Authentication" };
return msg;
```

Comment: That does the same as the above.

Comment: Having a similar code, it does return an http 401. Try to see if you are not using any [Global Filters or OWIN specifics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149750/owin-unauthorised-webapi-call-returning-login-page-rather-than-401) for login or other purpose that would be called bedore your controller method. Give a try to an simple empty project too, to validate taht this has to do with your project setup.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right, however when you have Owin for authenticating users all 401 responses seems to be intercepted to redirected to microsoft login page.
In this case you should see the login url in the response.

If you disable owin authentication your api will return 401 (ad it works even returning an object and without throwing exceptions)

[image: sample call from fiddler]