# jquery `$.post` `fail` fails after jQuery and Knockout update

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Before updating this apiPost method using `$.post` successfully handles `fail` (a `HTTPResponseMessage` with a  `401 Status Code` is returned from the api call) (`failure` and `always` are undefined in apiPost method calling code).

```
  self.modelIsValid = ko.observable(true);
  self.modelErrors = ko.observableArray();

  self.apiPost = function (uri, data, success, failure, always) {
        self.isLoading(true);
        self.modelIsValid(true);
        $.post(rootPath + uri, data)
            .done(success)
            .fail(function (result) {
                if (failure == null) {
                    if (result.status != 400)
                        self.modelErrors([result.status + ':' +
                          result.statusText + ' - ' + result.responseText]);
                    else
                        self.modelErrors(JSON.parse(result.responseText));
                  self.modelIsValid(false);
                }
                else
                    failure(result);
            })
            .always(function () {
                if (always == null)
                    self.isLoading(false);
                else
                    always();
            });
    };
```

When stepping through the code the `fail` code block is hit and then dozens of lines of jquery, javascript, knockout and VM extension code is run before returning to the `fail` code block and the inner `if` and updating the `modelErrors` array and then setting the `modelIsValid` to false.

After updating the `fail` block is hit and the other code is then run but it never returns to the `fail` code block.  The array never gets updated and the `modelIsValid` is never set to false (a ValidationError partial view is triggered by `modelIsValid` being false).

Original versions: jquery -1.9.1 and knockout-2.2.1.

Updated versions: jquery -3.1.1 and knockout-3.4.2.

Running on Widnows 7 Ultimate, VS2015 and the lastest Chrome.  Debugging the javascript in Developer Tools.

Has something changed in jquery or knockout that breaks the `fail`.  How would I rewrite to fix the problem?

Comment: Very interesting. Could you compare response headers you get before and after the update? Or maybe you have errors breaking further execution of the script? AFAIK there were no breaking changes in Ajax `.fail(...)` functionality of jQuery since 1.9

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it had nothing to do with jQuery or Knockout.  The project I'm using the updated jQuery and Knockout in is using Identity 2.0 which incorporates OWIN, which redirects to the Login page on a 401.

See  [Unauthorised webapi call returning login page rather than 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149750/unauthorised-webapi-call-returning-login-page-rather-than-401)

I used Cuong Le's answer, posted 6/11/15.  The WebAPI call now returns the 401 with no redirect.