# Web Api call returns 302 error code (on Authentication failed) and additional response with login page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am facing a strange issue and unable to find a way out. I have a web api application which is working fine until it times out. At this point when i make a ajax call server response is empty and an additional response is received with Login URL.
[image: Web API CAll 1]

I thought of catching response and read location header to identify if it contains login URL with no success. How should we handle such scenario in web api ajax calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the [`SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.suppressformsauthenticationredirect(v=vs.110).aspx) property to prevent this behavior. For example in your `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication context = (HttpApplication)sender;
    context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
}
```

Setting this will have a global impact over both your ASP.NET MVC and Web API parts.

If you want to do this only for your Web API endpoints, you could inspect the `context.Request.Url` and conditionally do it only for `/api` endpoints.

If you are using newer versions of the framework you might also consider reading [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149750/unauthorised-webapi-call-returning-login-page-rather-than-401).