# Xero webhook not working says "Response contained a body"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, webhooks, xero-api

I am trying to get a webhook setup with Xero working locally. I am using ngrok to allow xero to call my localhost. To get the webhook working I must correctly return the "intent to receive"

It seems to be working fine in that I can debug it and follow it through. However when I try to return 200 for success (hashes match) or 401 unauthorized (hashes don't match) the receiving Xero still doesn't accept it. All it says is: "Response contained a body"

According to the [Xero webhook docs](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/webhooks/configuring-your-server) my endpoint must ensure:

1. It uses HTTPS
2. It responds within 5 seconds with a 200 O.K status code
3. **There is no body in the response**
4. There are no cookies in the response headers
5. If the signature is invalid a 401 Unauthorised status code is returned

I have tried returning the code in various ways:

```
public IHttpActionResult WebHooks()
{
    //if hash check fails I tried these
    return Unauthorized();
    return Request.CreateResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    
    //if hash check matched I tried the following
    return Ok();
    return Request.CreateResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    
}
```

In seething desperation I also tried

```
public int WebHooks()
{
    //if hash check matches
    return 200;
    //if hash check fails
    return 401;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help. I spent too long searching for an existing answer, but I couldn't find any. What am I doing wrong? As far as I can see my webapi should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing I tried worked and my swear-jar overfloweth. I noticed through ngrok that the "intent to receive" would return a 302 (as opposed to 401) and then would redirect to Account/Login.

This led me down a rabbit hole to where I discovered [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28713392/1652234)

To quote:

> If you are adding asp.net WebApi inside asp.net MVC web site you
> probably want to respond unauthorized to some requests. But then
> ASP.NET infrastructure come into play and when you try to set response
> status code to HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized you will get 302 redirect
> to login page.

That was exactly the behaviour I saw. When I tried the webhook in a new webapi project with only one method - it worked. However I want to get it working in my MVC site. I added what this post suggested and it now works perfectly for me.

Many thanks to @Jacob Alley

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. This is what I did to get it working:

```
            if (hashedPayload != xeroSignature)
            {
                ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
                return Content(string.Empty);
            }

            ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            return Content(string.Empty);
```

Comment: In webapi controller, ControllerContext does not contain a definition for HttpContext. 

Are you using regular .net framework MVC controller, a web api controller or dotnet core?

Thank you for your help by the way

Comment: I think for your case HttpContext.Current.Response  should work instead of ControllerContext.HttpContext.

Comment: anyway you wanna accept this answer? i see you gave me a shoutout in yours

Comment: I don't want to accept your answer because it wasn't the answer for my particular issue.